# Temporarily stopping array loop

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    char choice = 'Y';
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int q=1;
    int j=0;
    String[] name = new String[q];
    while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'){
            for(; j<q; j++){
            System.out.print("Input student name: ");
            name[j] = input.nextLine();
            }
        System.out.print("Input another student? (Y/N): ");
        choice = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
        q++;
    }
        System.out.println(name[0]);
    }
}
```

I wanted to know if it is possible and how to temporarily stop an array loop and continue after the loop. Is it also possible to do this using basic array program?

I tried making an array without a predetermined value.
I expected that it will stop if the q variable is met and every time the user input "y" the q variable will increase making the array loop function again.
It didn't work after the 1st output.

Comment: I think your outer `while` loop is correct, but the inner `for` loop is not working.  In fact I don't think you need the `for` loop at all, just use `name[j++]` to put the student name in the right index.

Answer (score 0):

"The array is a specified-length data structure whereas ArrayList is a variable-length Collection class."
And here you are trying to add the length of the array.
You can either set the variable q as the max number of names the array can have or use ArrayList.
There is no problem in the loop with the way you wrote your code.

Comment: a code snippet would assist in the answer